Doubt regarding Four Hinged Rods in Equilibrium
Question:
Four identical uniform rods are connected in series and hanging from the ceiling, with perfectly smooth (frictionless) joints between them. The system is in equilibrium. Let

α be the angle the first rod makes with the horizontal, and

β be the angle the second rod makes with respect to the first rod. I need to calculate the ratio
tan
⁡

tan
⁡

tanβ
tanα.
I know the answer is
3
3, but I’m having trouble figuring out how to derive it. Here's what I’ve thought about so far:
I know this problem involves equilibrium, so the forces and torques acting on each rod must balance.
I suspect that the geometry of the system and the relationships between the tensions in the rods play a key role, but I’m not sure how to set up the equations.
I’ve also read that this could be solved using the principle of virtual work, but I don’t fully understand how that applies here.
Could someone help me understand which concepts or steps I should focus on to solve this? Any guidance would be appreciate


Do not repost the same closed question. This can get you banned.

oh im sorry, im new to this platform, wasnt aware about the rules, mb

Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837541/2451

Hi akash bansal. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

could you help me with an idea to solve, or help me with a logic im missing
